# Storing nonrelational data on Azure

Tags: azure, nosql, azure-sql-database

We are building a platform for charity and we want to log all activities that are happening. For example

- John Doe (link) has donated 20$ to project Children in need (link)
- John Doe (link) has joined team Architects (link)
- John Doe (link) became friend with Dane Doe (link)
- Project Children (link) posted a new photo (photo)
  ...

So it's similar to Facebook wall. Question is how to store this on Azure? Currently we are using Azure SQL and we store certain fields in JSON in then based on another field we render the activity. But we cannot search in that data etc which is really bad.

I have checked [Table Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/) which is perfect for that. Only problem is performance and ordering. Many said it's really slow to search by nonindexed field + we need ordering (I dunno whats the default ordering here, probably ASC - somewhere we need DESC, elsewhere ASC).

Others suggested to have Lucene.net, just to store data somewhere and have lucene index the data. Then we can easily search and order. Only problem is updating index (when we do something on platform, it has to show immediately, so we cannot rebuild index on 1h or so). I know we can probably update index and just reindex records that younger that some date. It could work.

Third option is installing nosql database like mongodb. But reading online, nobody is has confirmed if it works. But I did notice there is a mongodb in Azure store.

What do you suggest? Did anybody had a problem similar to this and how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

lucene.net is a nice solution, it can provide you near-real time search. please go through a book called "Lucene in action". although it's meant for java version but most of the things are same in .net edition. see if it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Realistically, indexes on relational database tables are sub-tables themselves. With that in mind, maintaining indexes in Azure table storage is really a matter of having additional  tables or rows which serve as indexes. What you give up with the NoSQL paradigm is really the ACID properties of relational databases and that is something you would then need to take care of, in your application. (How to do this is really beyond the scope of this answer and depends on your requirements).

Answering you question, you need to store both links to enable efficient queries. For example, your person-friend link would need to have both associations; they could be in the same or in two separate tables. Something like, John Doe – Dane Doe, Friend and Dana Doe – John Doe, Friend. Then you would have an index on both John and Dana, and be able to get all their friends with an efficient query.

If you do not really have any scalability needs, I would recommend going the Azure SQL route instead of the Table Storage route. ACID properties are difficult to implement at the application layer and it is ACID which make the relational database so dependable.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at using graph databases like [Neo4J](http://neo4j.org/)?

here's a video of a real-life production neo4j app on Azure: http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2012/06/18/new-talks-neo4j-in-a-net-world-and-youre-in-production-now-what/